I have a spring backend and an Angular frontend in the same WildFly, why is my frontend URL mistaken with backend by Spring?
I'm making a web application that is supposed to run on a WildFly.
The backend and the frontend are put in the same .war package and this used to work fine before I implemented Angular's internationalization. Now, if I try to reach my Angular URL:
http://wildFlyUrl/warName/en-US/#
I get a 404 not found.
What I suppose it's happening is that the back-end is capturing this URL thinking it's its own, because if I remove the back-end from the package I can reach the URL just fine.
This is my current folder structure inside the war.
How do you think I could prevent this? Let me know if you need snippets of code of either applications
